# basic Replacement of row in select

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am pretty new with MySQL and my question is

How could I make it so in the selection I make the "Bike_ID" instead show the "bike_name" but match with the orders table?

It shows:

```
# Orders_ID, Bike_ID, Serial_Number
    '1',       '4',     '204358'
```

What I want the selection to show:

```
# Orders_ID, Bike_name, Serial_Number
    '1',       'Honda Monkey',     '204358'
```

I added two screenshots from the shell of the tables.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a simple join:

```
select o.orders_id, m.bike_name, o.serial_number
from orders o
inner join motorbike m on m.bike_id = o.bike_id
where o.customer_id = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, I have not touched join too much yet. I read up on it more.